# Where does Docker image initial filesystem come from?

Tags: docker, docker-build, python-manylinux

I'm looking at `manylinux1` stock image build scripts at https://github.com/pypa/manylinux, specifically the call chain:

- `.travis.yml`

  ```
  <...>
  script:
    - docker build --rm -t quay.io/pypa/manylinux1_$PLATFORM:$TRAVIS_COMMIT -f docker/Dockerfile-$PLATFORM docker/
  ```
- `docker/Dockerfile-<arch>`:

  ```
  COPY build_scripts /build_scripts
  RUN bash build_scripts/build.sh
  ```
- `docker/build_scripts/build.sh`:

  ```
  <a bunch of variables>
  sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/' /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf
  <...>
  ```

The script assumes that a base CentOS 5 filesystem (e.g. `/etc/yum`) is already present. **Where does it come from?**

I don't see any references to a stock image, or anything like downloading it from somewhere, or using an installation ISO. Neither is there an `/etc` anywhere in the codebase.

Comment: I am not sure I understood ur question , the `/etc/yum` is already in the base centos image `docker run -it centos ls /etc/yum`

Comment: Well, I don't see any references to that "base CentOS image" (all the more, CentOS _5_ image) in the code. Where does it come from and how does Docker know it should use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile-x86_64) for the manylinux image, you can see that it is based on `centos:5.11`

```
FROM centos:5.11
MAINTAINER The ManyLinux project
...
```

The `/etc/yum` folder is already part of the centos image, which can be verified by running: `docker run -it centos:5.11 ls /etc/yum`

**Update:**

Docker images are built in a layer structure defined inside a Dockerfile. Images build on top of each other, by using the [FROM syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) inside a Dockerfile.

In this case, the image is based on `centos:5.11` image. The syntax is explained at [docker tag | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) (go figure). In this case, there's no directory address, which means it's retrieved from [`centos` entry](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/centos/) in the default [Docker Hub registry](https://hub.docker.com/explore/), the one with the [`5.11` tag](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/centos/tags/).

The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/37e0a7f3d98ae875dac7ae1026e99c1c04524c62/docker/Dockerfile) for CentOS is very simple. It just expands a tarball with the base CentOS file structure into a `scratch` (empty) docker image. This tarball, `centos-7-docker.tar.xz` in the case of the latest version, contains the `/etc/yum` folder, among others.

Comment: Okay, could you add a link to the docs explaining the `centos:5.11` syntax (`docker run` help doesn't do it)? It must mean to take it from some "default" online image directory -- which one, can I browse it?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev updated answer to make it more clearer.

Comment: Added the few missing bits. Now it's perfect.